# load svg with Cairo

Tags: c++, svg, cairo

I want to load a SVG file with the Cairo library, do apply some transformations to it.
Then I want to display my svg with a glTexture.

But I just find functions which create svg file and not load svg.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cairo itself cannot read SVG files. You need something like [librsvg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Librsvg) to render SVGs to a Cairo surface.

From a quick look at their [API documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/2.40/), it looks like you need `rsvg_handle_new_from_file()` to load a file and something like `rsvg_handle_render_cairo()` or `rsvg_handle_get_pixbuf()` to draw the SVG to a Cairo context / to turn the SVG into a GdkPixbuf.