# Render SVG from file to Cairo canvas in Julia

Tags: julia, cairo

Is there a way to load an SVG from file and then render it to a Cairo canvas? Ideally something like:

```
image = read_from_svg("my.svg")
set_source_surface(cr, image, 0, 0)
paint(cr)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load svg with Cairo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152068/load-svg-with-cairo)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709243/create-cairo-path-from-svg-file?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It sounds like there is no built-in way to do it in Julia atm. It may be possible to call librsvg through a C++ binding. The CairoSVG thing doesn't look like it would give me an internal object that I can call set_source_surface() on, and I don't want to convert to PNG externally and then load that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Rsvg.jl](https://github.com/lobingera/Rsvg.jl) package that wraps the [rsvg](https://wiki.gnome.org/LibRsvg?action=show) library. The package can be installed with `Pkg.add("Rsvg")`. You might have to troubleshoot the installation of the native Cairo and Rsvg libraries -- the package will attempt to do this automatically, but it is a difficult problem based on the multitude of different configurations.

Using that package, it seems be possible to do what you want. From the package's README:

```
using Rsvg
using Cairo

filename_in = "a4.svg"

r = Rsvg.handle_new_from_file(filename_in);
d = Rsvg.handle_get_dimensions(r);
cs = Cairo.CairoImageSurface(d.width,d.height,Cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32);
c = Cairo.CairoContext(cs);
Rsvg.handle_render_cairo(c,r);
```